# cant use fonts in fonts directory

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have inserted the fonts but I can't see them. I don't know why there is no space in between the words.

```
<html>

<head>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="topbar">

      </div>
      <nav id="main">
        <a href="/" id="logo"><img src="logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>


        <ul id="main-menu">
          <li><a href=""></a>Η ΟΜΟΣΠΟΝΔΙΑ</a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a>ΑΡΚΑΔΩΝ ΕΡΓΑ</a></li>          
          <li><a href=""></a>ΕΠΩΝΥΜΟΙ ΑΡΚΑΔΕΣ</a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a>ΝΕΑ - ΕΝΗΜΕΡΩΣΗ</a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a>ΕΠΙΣΚΕΨΗ ΣΤΗΝ ΑΡΚΑΔΙΑ</a></li>
          <li><a href=""></a>ΑΝΑΖΗΤΗΣΕΙΣ ΣΤΗΝ ΑΡΚΑΔΙΑ</a></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family:Proxima Nova ;
  src: url(./fonts/Proxima\ Nova\ Regular.otf);
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family:Proxima Nova ;
  src: url(./fonts/Proxima\ Nova\ Bold.otf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansPro ;
  src: url(./fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: SourceSansPro  ;
  src: url(./fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular', serif;
  }
  
  header {
    background: url('./images/bg.png') bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 750px;
  }
  
  #topbar {
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  nav#main {
    background-color:white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
    #logo{
    position: absolute;
      display: block;
    border: 10px solid #AB0427;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: 50px;
   top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
   #logo img{
   display: block;
   }  
   .container{
    width: 1360;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }
#main-menu{
margin: 0;
padding: 0 20px 0 320px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 60px;
list-style: none;

}
#main-menu a {
color:#002868 ;
font size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Are Latin characters invisible too, or just Greek ones?

Comment: greek ones only

Comment: @OmarL GREEK ONES ONLY

Answer (score 1):

Try Using Formats and make sure the path is correct

**Note**: Remove the spaces if there are no spaces is in the filename, change the backward slash into forwarding slash

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"Proxima Nova" ;
  src: url(./fonts/Proxima/Nova/Regular.otf) format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family:"Proxima Nova";
  src: url(./fonts/Proxima/Nova/Bold.otf) format("opentype");
  font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "SourceSansPro";
  src: url(./fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "SourceSansPro";
  src: url(./fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have backslashes in the urls of the top two. I'd check to make sure the filepath is correct, that may be part of the problem.
Additionally, you could try to add a format property like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Proxima Nova ;
  src: url(./fonts/Proxima/Nova/Regular.otf) format("open-type");
  font-weight: normal;
```

Comment: First of all thank you for helping but still nothing and second off all the #main-menu a isn't working too an i dont know why.